# Подтормаживает Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ос

После установки ubuntu в качестве основной системы, начал замечать, что несистемные приложения медленно запускаются. Как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: опиши подробнее проблему.. насколько медленно, что за приложения?

Comment: Грубо говоря, любые не предустановленные программы грузятся минимум по полторы-две минуты, а вот все системные летают. По железу, вот ссылка - http://www.dell.com/ru/business/p/latitude-15-5590-laptop/pd  @СергейПетрашко

Comment: так долго?... жесть .. еще и ssd ?

Comment: при загрузке проц и оперативка сильно  грузятся?

Comment: Я если честно сам не понимаю в чем тут дело, но на данный момент я с этим живу ))) @СергейПетрашко

Comment: Нагрузка выше 15% не поднимается  @СергейПетрашко

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81104/discussion-between---and-v-kvach).